# Getting the file if openFileOutput is used

Tags: android

I am saving my file to app's private internal storage like this then I pass that file into a Uri so I can return it as a result in my other activity

```
String filename = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(data);
    outputStream.close();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile("")); //pass file here somehow
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    finish();

} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Error creating file " + e.getMessage(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

How do you get the File from `openFileOutput` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you get the File from openFileOutput ?

Use `Context.getFilesDir()` for getting file path which is created using `openFileOutput` method:

```
String rootDir = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(rootDir + filename);
.....
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Comment: Yes, though you don't actually have to bother with concatenating the path and name yourself, as there's a 2-argument constructor for File which takes a directory as well as a filename.

Answer (score 1):

I made this solution for the very same problem, I like this one better:

```
Uri internalFilesUri = Uri.fromFile(getContext().getFilesDir());
Uri fileUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(internalFilesUri , filename);
```